# ng2-dnd how use class css when drag dragOver dropOver for angular2

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd
this is a demo for this drag&drop using angular2
so how can I affect my class css to indicate that this zone is the droppable zone

[image]

this is a part of code from github source project

```
 _onDragEnterCallback(event: MouseEvent) {
     if (this._dragDropService.isDragged) {
         this._elem.classList.add(this._config.onDragEnterClass);
         this.onDragEnter.emit({dragData: this._dragDropService.dragData, mouseEvent: event});
     }
 }
```

how can I affect my class to this line                  `this._elem.classList.add(this._config.onDragEnterClass);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see it emits `onDragEnter` event so you need to subscribe to it.

For example:

```
<div dnd-draggable
    [dragEnabled]="true"
    [dropZones]="['zone1']"
    (onDragEnter)="myEventHandler($event)">
```

Then inside `myEventHandler()` you can do whatever you want.

By the way, you could also use something like this without any extra methods:

```
<div dnd-draggable
    [class.highlighted]="highlightMe"
    [dragEnabled]="true"
    [dropZones]="['zone1']"
    (onDragEnter)="highlightMe=true"
    (onDragLeave)="highlightMe=false">
```

Comment: [class.highlighted]="highlightMe" - but if you got several dropszones with the same class, how do you reference that for this exact one I would like to have the class enabled?

Answer (score 2):

The dnd-droppable will receive the `dnd-drag-over` CSS class while there is a draggable over it. You may try providing styles for it instead of utilising TypeScript, e.g.

```
/* Utilising SCSS on this example */
.my-droppable {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    &.dnd-drag-over {
      /* Changes the border color while a draggable hovers it */
      border-color: #ccc;
    }
}
```

The complete list of classes can be found on the [DragDropConfig class](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd/blob/master/src/dnd.config.ts).